# Проблема с установкой плагина Easy Fancybox для Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cms

Установил плагин Easy Fancybox для Wordpress 4.3, но после установки изображения на сайте не открываются в модальном окне, а в консоли вижу уведомление:

Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).fancybox is not a function

Понимаю, что проблема кроется в том, что подключается версия jQuery, несовместимая с плагином. Однако новые версии поверх основной (1.11.3) я не подключал.

Посмотрел код страницы и увидел перед закрывающим тегом body подключаемые плагином скрипты:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://website/wp-content/plugins/easy-fancybox/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.7.min.js?ver=1.5.7'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://website/wp-content/plugins/easy-fancybox/jquery.easing.pack.js?ver=1.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://website/wp-content/plugins/easy-fancybox/jquery.mousewheel.min.js?ver=3.1.12'></script>
```

В то время как в head-е страницы загружается

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://website/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.3'></script>
```

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с похожей проблемой? Куда копать и что делать? 
Избавляться от стандартной jQuery я не хочу.

Comment: Такая же проблема наблюдается и с плагином Fancybox for Wordpress

Comment: `jQuery(...).fancybox is not a function` - это не на `jQuery` ругается! В коде  идет попытка вызвать `fancybox`, но он еще не определен! Может стоит код в `jQuery(document).ready()` обернуть?

Comment: @borodatych, руками Fancybox я также пробовал подключить, оборачивал как раз в jQuery(document).ready(). Не помогло, проблема та же.

Comment: Используйте не устаревшую версию Fancybox, а актуальную (на данный момент 2.1.5) http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ Версии 1.3.x не работают с последними jQuery первой ветки. Я для 1.3.4 вносил изменения в код. P.S. Правда у меня ошибка другая была, если память не изменяет. P.P.S. Тут можно глянуть список глюков найденных https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ нашелся в собственной невнимательности. 
В подвале сайта случайно переподключил jQuery. Убрал строку - проблема решилась.